# angular2-date-picker - only current date-time is displayed

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, datetime

I am using angular2-date-picker plugin in my angular project, I want to display current time - 5 minutes, so I've written modifyDate() in my component.ts file

**component.ts**:

```
      modifyDate() {
      let modifiedDate=new Date();
      modifiedDate.setMinutes(modifiedDate.getMinutes()-5);
      console.log("modified: "+modifiedDate);
      return modifiedDate;
     }


     //datetime picker
     startDate: Date =this.modifyDate();
     settings = {
     bigBanner: true,
     timePicker: true,
     format: 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a',
     defaultOpen: false,
     closeOnSelect:false
};
```

there is **component.html** file :

```
    <angular2-date-picker class="form-control" id="datetimepicker" (onDateSelect)="onDateSelect($event)"  name="datetime" [(ngModel)]="startDate" [settings]="settings"></angular2-date-picker>
```

After building above code, in my DOM I get the next lines:

[image]

As you can see, in  tag,  ng-reflect-model has correct data assigned, but below, in  element, I get a current datetime anyway and therefore, in my application is displayed current time. can you suggest any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to replicate the issue that you're facing. Maybe there is something missing to make it work...

relevant **HTML**:

```
<angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [settings]="settings" name="angular-calendar" (onDateSelect)="onDateSelect($event)"
 ngDefaultControl></angular2-date-picker>
<br/>
    <p>
        Time from selection: <mark> {{date | date:'EE, MMM d, y, H:mm:ss zzzz' }}</mark>
    </p>
    <p>
        minus 5 minutes: <mark>{{newVar}}</mark>
    </p>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  date = new Date();
  newVar: string = '';
  datePulled:boolean=false;
  settings = {
    bigBanner: true,
    timePicker: true,
    format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
    defaultOpen: true
  }
  constructor() {
    /* Update #2 */
    if(!this.datePulled){
      let someVar = new Date(this.date);
      someVar.setMinutes(someVar.getMinutes() - 5);
      this.date = someVar;
      this.datePulled = true;
    }
  }
  onDateSelect(evt) {
    if(!this.datePulled){
      let someVar = new Date(this.date);
      someVar.setMinutes(someVar.getMinutes() - 5);
      /* Update #1 */
      this.date = someVar;
      this.newVar = someVar.toString();
      console.log(evt, ' & date:', this.newVar);
    this.datePulled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lcgpy4)

**update #1**: as per requestor's comment, the original selected date is pulled back 5 minutes

**update #2**: as per requestor's comment, the date which is loaded on page load is also pulled back 5 minutes

**update #3**: as per requestor's comment, the timepicker is now set to true;

[image]

Comment: is it possible to display the time with minus five minutes in <angular2-date-picker>  tag next to the date?

Comment: @T.S, yes, possible and updated the answer to get the original date pulled back by 5 minutes... attached screenshot for it also

Comment: As I can see it works only when the date is selected, I wanted to display current datetime-five minutes in calendar box when in settings there is  timePicker:true, so when the user enters, he wills see current datetime - five minutes. Sorry If my explanation is not very clear

Comment: What is the reason for that need? A user wouldn't check inspect element... As soon as they make a selection, we will get 5 minute adjustment

Comment: In my project I need to filter data by date. I have two calendars, the user should choose the start date from the first calendar, and the end date from the second calendar, In the end-date calendar I  want to show current date and time, whereas in the start-date calendar I want to display date and time - 5 minutes.

Comment: @T.S, the by-default date (on page load) is also pulled back by 5 minutes... stackblitz and answer both updated

Comment: thank you, can you please add in settings : [timePicker: true] and show me if it will be displayed current datetime pulled back by 5 minutes?

Comment: @T.S you can check now

Comment: You can show me your appreciation by marking this answer as accepted and up voting it also :)